# top rounded corners in my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this jquery for my menu buttons, what I want is to get top-corner rounded for my menu, this is a whole code:

```
    <html>
<style type="text/css">
#menuBarHolder { width: 860px; height:45px; background-color:#000; color:#fff; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; margin-top:20px;}
#menuBarHolder ul{ list-style-type:none; display:block;}
.firstchild { border-left:1px solid #ccc;}
#container { margin-top:10px;}
#menuBar li{  float:left;  padding:15px; height:16px; width:70px; border-right:1px solid #ccc; }
#menuBar li a{color:#fff; text-decoration:none; letter-spacing:-1px; font-weight:bold;}
.menuHover { background-color:#999;}
.menuInfo { cursor:hand; background-color:#000; color:#fff; width:74px; font-size:11px;height:100px; padding:3px; display:none;  position:absolute; margin-left:-15px; margin-top:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;   -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-radius-bottomright: 5px;border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
}

</style>

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
#menuBar li a{width:50px;}
.menuInfo { margin-left:-65px; width:80px;}
</style>

<![endif]-->

<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

$('#menuBar li').click(function()
{
  var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  document.location.href = url;

});

$('#menuBar li').hover(function()
{

   $(this).find('.menuInfo').slideDown();
},
function()
{

  $(this).find('.menuInfo').slideUp();

});

});
</script>
<center>
<div id="menuBarHolder">
<ul id="menuBar">
<li class="firstchild"><a href="javascript:#">Home</a><div class="menuInfo">I am some text about the home section</div></li>
<li><a href="javascript:#">About Us</a><div class="menuInfo">I am some text about the services section</div></li>
<li><a href="javascript:#">News</a><div class="menuInfo">I am some text about the clients section</div></li>
<li><a href="javascript:#">Equipment</a><div class="menuInfo">I am some text about the portfolio section</div></li>
<li><a href="javascript:#">Services</a><div class="menuInfo">I am some text about the about section</div></li>
<li><a href="javascript:#">Project</a><div class="menuInfo">I am some text about the blog section</div></li>
<li><a href="javascript:#">Contact Us</a><div class="menuInfo">I am some text about the follow section</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code of **CSS3** should do it:

Add below code inside within the body of the `<head>` tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
</style>
```

But note that currently only modern browsers support the **CSS3**.

**Note:** For cross-browser solution, you can use the:

**[JQuery Curvy Corners Plugin](http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html)**

So if you **really** want curved corners, I would recommend you to go with JQuery Curvy Corners Plugin.

**Great Resource:**

Create your own corners here:

http://border-radius.com/

Comment: @Sohail, the CSS either goes in the css stylesheet `#element_needing_rounded_corners {/* css3 stuff */}` or inside `<style>` tags in the `<head>` of the html page.

Answer (score 0):

According to your CSS above you're only specifying that the bottom left and bottom right should be rounded.

If you want top left and top right rounded instead change:

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
```

To

```
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
```

If you want all four corners rounded just do:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try look at [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) , it got themes too,

if i want to make all my div content cornered i just do like this,

```
<div class="ui-wiget-content ui-corner-all">bla bla</div>
```

they've just have all the class setup.

you can examine their css file to know how their do it, but its not work for IE, huhuhu.